# Remove generics from interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is there a way to remove generic from interface?
code sample:

**I have:**

```
interface ServerMessages {
  [ActionType.EVENT_1]: ResponseEventBody1;
  [ActionType.EVENT_2]: ResponseEventBody2;
  [ActionType.EVENT_3]: ResultModifier<ResponseEventBody3>;
  [ActionType.EVENT_4]: ResponseEventBody4;
  [ActionType.EVENT_5]: ResultModifier<ResponseEventBody5>;
  [ActionType.EVENT_6]: ResultModifier<ResponseEventBody6>;
  [ActionType.EVENT_7]: ResponseEventBody7;
}
```

```
interface ResultModifier<T> {
  success: boolean;
  payload: T;
  error?: SomeError;
}
```

**What I want to receive:**

```
interface ServerMessagesWithoutGenerics {
  [ActionType.EVENT_1]: ResponseEventBody1;
  [ActionType.EVENT_2]: ResponseEventBody2;
  [ActionType.EVENT_3]: ResponseEventBody3;
  [ActionType.EVENT_4]: ResponseEventBody4;
  [ActionType.EVENT_5]: ResponseEventBody5;
  [ActionType.EVENT_6]: ResponseEventBody6;
  [ActionType.EVENT_7]: ResponseEventBody7;
}
```

I have searched already for 3 hours, but haven't found an answer. Would be glad for help

Comment: What is `ResultModifier`? Please edit to make a [mcve]. The solution will depend on how `ResultModifier` is defined, or there may not be a possible solution.

Comment: @kaya3 understood. Just added an interface for `ResultModifier`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution using a conditional type with an inferred parameter:

```
type Unmodify<T> = T extends ResultModifier<infer U> ? U : T
type UnmodifyInterface<T> = {[K in keyof T]: Unmodify<T[K]>}

type ServerMessagesWithoutGenerics = UnmodifyInterface<ServerMessages>
```

Note that this will give incorrect results if any of the `ResponseEventBody` types happen to be assignable to `ResultModifier<U>` for some `U`.

Comment: that's worked like a magic. Will look into the definition of `infer` in docs.
Many hours thanks